# Error: XMLHttpRequest error. in flutter web whenever i call a local sms to client

Tags: flutter

i am having an issue of Error: XMLHttpRequest error. inside my flutter web for api calling.its working on mobile version but throwing an error while running in chrome

here is my header section
headers:
{
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":
'true', // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
"Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale",
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS"
});

can anyone help me

Comment: CORS error......

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't allow cross origin access. See [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS).

If the server allows it, then it will respond to the preflight request with an Access-Control-Allow-Methods response header. E.g.

```
OPTIONS /resource/foo
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, x-requested-with
Origin: https://foo.bar.org

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.bar.org
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

Comment: how can i allow cors acess